# Michael Spivak's Calculus - Chapter 1 problem 5.10

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing

The problem says

If $a,b \ge 0$ and $a^2 \lt b^2$, then $a \lt b$. (Hint use previous problem backwards)

The previous problem proved if 0 $\le$ a$\lt$b then $a^2 \lt b^2$

When I see this problem I don't understand how you can turn the problem around and it always holds. I'd think that you'd have to prove that if AND ONLY IF $0 \le a \lt b$ will $a^2 \lt b^2$.

Is this train of thought correct? The hint makes it seem this is a simple reference to the previous problem, like all you'd have to say is "because of previous problem" you'd only need one or two lines.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. Please [edit] the question to finish the statement of the "previous problem". Possible hint: you want to show that if $b^2 - a^2 = (b-a)(b+a) > 0$ then $b-a > 0$.

Comment: Oh I apologize. I saw the entire post when I clicked on edit so I assumed me not being able to see the entire post was on my end. Thank you very much for pointing that out.

Comment: Again thanks for pointing that out. I was confused thinking there was some sort of invisible character limit, but my improper formatting just cut off half of my post. I think everything is in order now.

Comment: Plug in some example a and b values. Use combinations of positive and negative numbers. See how the hypothesis applies. Can you find a way yo make the hypothesis of the previous problem turn into the hypothesis of this one?

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$0 < b^2 - a^2 = (b - a)(b + a)$
Prove b + a is positive.  Thus b - a is positive.

Comment: Thank you, this makes good sense